# Downloading Issues from a Public GitHub Repository

Tags: curl, github, permissions

I want to download issues from [Jabref](https://github.com/JabRef/jabref), an open-source citation tool.

I looked up how to do this, and it looks like the way everyone does it is through curl like this ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41369365/how-can-i-export-github-issues-to-excel)):

```
curl -i "https://api.github.com/repos/<repo-owner>/<repo-name>/issues" -u "<user-name>"
```

The problem is that I'm not the owner of the repository, so I'm not sure what to fill in for repo-owner. I also don't know who the owner is, since apparently Github hides that information, but even if I did I probably wouldn't have the required permissions.

Is anyone allowed to download issues from public repositories, or do you have to be a collaborator? If anyone is allowed, what should I fill in for repo-owner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of the public repository https://github.com/JabRef/jabref, the repoèowner is simply `JabRef`.

```
curl -i "https://api.github.com/repos/JabRef/jabref/issues" -u "<user-name>"
```

This uses the [GitHub API "List issues for a repository"](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#list-issues-for-a-repository), available for anyone on public repositories.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some Python code that does the trick for me.

```py
def download_github_issues_as_dict(repo_url, token):
    '''
    since GitHub doesn't make it super easy to download GitHub issues...
    :param repo_url: the full URL of the repo (don't include the trailing "/").
    :param token: a GitHub Personal Access Token (create from GitHub itself)
    :return: a dictionary that can be easily json-ified with the relevant info from the issues.
    '''
    assert isinstance(repo_url, str) and not repo_url.endswith("/") and "/" in repo_url, "need nice repo_url"
    assert isinstance(token, str), "need nice token"
    import github  # pip install PyGithub
    g = github.Github(token)
    user_str, repo_str = repo_url.replace("https://github.com/", "").split("/")
    user = g.get_user(user_str)
    repo = user.get_repo(repo_str)
    issues = repo.get_issues(state="all")
    # the number 30 appears to hardcoded into the PyGitHub - maybe there is a better way to do this part?
    real_issues = [_ for i in range(round(issues.totalCount / 30) + 1) for _ in issues.get_page(i) if
                   not _.pull_request]
    rtn = {}
    for iss in real_issues:
        iss_dict = {"title": iss.title,
                    "body": iss.body,
                    "state": iss.state,
                    "comments": [_.body for _ in iss.get_comments()]}
        rtn[iss.number] = iss_dict
    return rtn
```